# Returning a view based on a if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement

I am trying to return a view based on a simple if condition but not able to do so. It seems like i am missing a very simple stuff in somewhere but couldnt figured it out.

What i am trying to do is return different views based on user ids.

If the below code is "usercontext.UserId != 1" it works! But it doesnt work for usercontext.UserId == 1. What am i missing here?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserProfile usercontext = new UserProfile();
        if (usercontext.UserId == 1) {
            return View(db.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == 2).ToList());
        }
        else { 
        return View(db.Employees.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Comment: because UserId is always 0

Comment: How? Can you explain me please?

Comment: because you instantiate it in the line right above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have empty usercontext model and UserId property is default (0 for int). You have to find different way to find UserId.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the UserId Correctly.Try this code

```
var usercontext = new UserProfile();
var userid = User.Identity.UserId;
if (userid == 1) {
   ...rest of the code
```